# how to get information about health metrics (like DB health) in marklogic server through management API in marklogic?

Tags: marklogic, health-monitoring, prometheus-node-exporter

I want information about health metrics for forest, appserver, host and cluster like

1. Health and disk space warning or alert for forest
2. Health status of Appservers.
3. Alert on log size, when it exceed.
4. Replication status of database.

using Management API or API that used as part of 8002 monitoring port as we have to create Prometheus endpoints based on that to expose it to grafana.

Answer (score 0):

For many of the things that you are looking to monitor, the Manage API can be used to retrieve configuration and status, and you can retrieve filtered log events.

The [Manage /v2/logs](https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/REST/GET/manage/v2/logs) endpoint and specify `regex` to filter for relevant log messages. You can use the `format` parameter to retrieve the information in `json`, `xml`, `html`, or `text` format, whichever is easier to parse and process.

1. Health and disk space warning or alert for forest
   https://help.marklogic.com/knowledgebase/article/View/49/16/recovering-from-low-disk-space

You could look for signs of trouble by periodically scanning for signs of trouble:

- SVC-FILWRT
- XDMP-MERGESPACE

http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/logs?filename=ErrorLog.txt&format=xml&regex=SVC-FILWRT|XDMP-MERGESPACE

2. Health status of Appservers.

To perform a basic HealthCheck, you could ping the HealthCheck port 7997 on each MarkLogic host. i.e. http://localhost:7997. That will let you know that the MarkLogic process is up and running on each host.

Depending upon what metrics you want to track for appserver health, you could use the [Manage /v2/servers](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/manage/v2/servers) endpoint in order to get request rates, cache ratios, etc.

http://localhost:8002/manage/LATEST/servers/App-Services?group-id=Default&view=status&format=xml

3. Alert on log size, when it exceed.

There isn't a configurable alert for log size. They are rotated daily, and have [a configurable retention policy](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/logfiles#id_76790).

You may need to monitor the filesystem capacity through some other means for proactive monitoring.

> When the log files are being written to a different device than the data files, it is possible to run out of space for logging. This does not appear to impact the servers ability to start, nor the availability of the forests, databases or app servers. Log entries will also still be written to /var/log/messages based on the configured OS logging level.

However, there will be log events if the log mount is full and cannot write, which you could retrieve via Manage /v2/logs, as shown above.

4. Replication status of database.

Are you referring to the status of a database and it's DR cluster, or forest HA replica?

In order to see the status of the cluster use [Manage /v2/clusters](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/manage/v2/clusters/%5Bid-or-name%5D@view=status)

For each database, you can get a list of the forests from the [Manage /v2/databases](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/manage/v2/databases)

http://localhost:8002/manage/LATEST/databases/Documents?view=status&format=html

and can verify the state from the [Manage /v2/forests](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/manage/v2/forests)

http://localhost:8002/manage/LATEST/forests/Documents?view=status&format=html